# Pointers to pointers to pointer equated to a pointer to a pointer. Not possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char *sr[] = {"manipuri","konkani","punjabi","hindi","telugu","maithili","odia"};
  char **pt[] = {sr+2,sr+4,sr+3,sr+1,sr+6}, ***r;
  r = pt;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++) ++r;
  cout << **r+3;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is how I understand it. 'sr' is a pointer to a character array. Its value is the address of "m" of "manipuri." 'pt' is an array of pointers to pointers of character arrays. It's value is an array of addresses to other pointers. 'r' is a single pointer to a pointer to a pointer of a character.

How is it possible then to assign 'pt' to 'r'? They are completely different data types. For one, 'r' points to a pointer that points to pointer that points to a pointer of a SINGLE character. While pt is an ARRAY that points to a pointer that pointer to an ARRAY of characters.

How is this possible?

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: Did you mean to write `for(int i=0;i<4;i++) { ++r;
  cout << **r+3; }`?

Comment: Pointers and arrays are distinct types, but arrays readily decay to pointers to the beginning of the array. Assigning `pt` to `r` assigns a pointer to the first element of `pt` (which would be a `char***`) to `r`.

Comment: Also you're just missing the `const` keyword: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a904f2a6a2f67ff

Answer (score 1):

> Here is how I understand it. 'sr' is a pointer to a character array.

`sr` is not a pointer. It is an array of pointers.

> Its value is the address of "m" of "manipuri".

Conceptually the value of the array is all of the elements of the array. However, when used in a value context, an array will decay to pointer to first element. The value of a pointer is a memory address.

> How is it possible then to assign 'pt' to 'r'? They are completely different data types.

Because just like `sr` and other arrays, `pt` too will decay to a pointer to first element. Elements of `pt` are of type `**char`. Therefore pointer to element of `pt` is `***char`. Which is the type of `r`.

> Not possible?

Yes, it is possible to assign an object of type `T[n]` to an object of type `T*`.

> While pt is an ARRAY that points to a pointer that pointer to an ARRAY of characters.

`pt` is an array. An array itself doesn't point. It contains pointers that each point to a pointer that points to a single character. It just so happens that single character is in an array (a character literal) - but that fact is in no way described by the type of `pt`.

---

PS. You're converting string literals to `char*`. Such implicit conversion has been ill-formed since C++11. Even before C++11, the conversion was deprecated.